# Timezone is incorrect [PHP]

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am developing locally on my computer with XAMPP, and I have never had problems with the timezone before. I used to live in DC, but moved to Berlin. As soon as I moved I changed the timezone to `date.timezone="Europe/Berlin"` and I haven't had any problems with that until now. Suddenly the timezone changed to America/New_York. I promptly changed it back in the php.ini file. But now for some reason only a couple pages on my website are recognizing the new timezone. On other pages when I type `date_default_timezone_get()` it still gives me America/New_York, while on other pages it gives me Europe/Berlin.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you also change `httpd.conf` and `my.ini`?

Comment: restart your apache and then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might not be the best answer but you can set the timezone on each separate page by the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Of course if you have a whole bunch of pages then that probably isn't a very good solution.

Comment: That's what include files are for. I trust you don't copy-paste the code to connect to the database every time you run a query, now do you? Personally I'd go for this. It's safer not to rely on configuration settings.

Comment: Well glad it helped, generally I just input those ini changes per page like in the case where one page might need like a 5 minute execution time and way more memory etc..